# Crear array completo de "seleccionar/desselecciona todo" (checkbox)

Tags: array, angular, typescript, checkbox

Estoy programando el típico seleccionar/deseleccionar todo, lo hace todo bien excepto una cosa, **si selecciono a mano un par de elementos y después le doy a seleccionar todos se queda el `array` vacío**.

```js
 seleccionarTodo() {
    if (this.capturaCochesId.length === 0) {
      for (let selec of this.coches) {
        this.capturaCochesId.push(selec.id);
        this.check = "checked";
      }
    } else {
      this.check = "";
      this.capturaCochesId = [];
    }
    console.log(this.capturaCochesId);
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" (change)="seleccionarTodo()"> SELECCIONAR TODO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te ocurre eso porque es lo que has definido en el código. Si la longitud de `this.capturaCochesId` es `0` pues de te selecciona todos. Sino lo pone vacío. Y en tu caso, cuando tienes algunos seleccionados ya no se cumple el `if` y pasa al `else`.

En vez de mirar `length` puedes comprobar si el checkbox está marcado o no y en función de eso marca o desmarcar todos.

```
seleccionarTodo(event) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.capturaCochesId = []; // reseteas el array de seleccionados para no tener duplicados ya que puedes tener items seleccionados previamente
      for (let selec of this.coches) {
        this.capturaCochesId.push(selec.id); 
      }
      this.check = "checked"; // esto lo puedes poner fuera del loop creo que no es necesario reasignar el valor en cada iteración.
    } else {
      this.check = "";
      this.capturaCochesId = [];
    }
    console.log(this.capturaCochesId);
}
```

Recuerda pasar `$event` desde la template.

```html
<input type="checkbox" (change)="seleccionarTodo($event)"> SELECCIONAR TODO
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias compañero quedo perfecto!!!!!